# Apache Hive: How to Add Column at Specific Location in Table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveddl

I want to add a new column to a specific location in hive table. when i add new column it goes to the last position.

Comment: Why does column order matter? When you view the data, query the correct ordering

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167597/in-hive-is-there-a-way-to-specify-between-which-columns-to-add-a-new-column-to/34200681#34200681) might help; although to be able specify `n`th position (instead of name of *preceding* column), you might have to do a bit of programming

Answer (score 3):

You need to recreate table. If the table is external and data already contains new column, then issue `drop` and `create table` statements. General solution is to:

```
1. create <new_table>...;
2. insert overwrite <new_table> select from <old_table>;
3. drop <old_table>;
4. alter table <new_table> rename to <old_table>;
```

Also if datafiles already contain new column in some position you can

```
1. Alter table add column
```

Change column position using this example:

```
2. ALTER TABLE test_change CHANGE old_name new_name STRING AFTER other_col CASCADE;
```

See docs here: [Change Column Name/Type/Position/Comment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment)

Comment: Instead of creating new, is there any alter way?

Comment: Step 4 should be `ALTER TABLE <new_table> RENAME TO <old_table>;`

Answer (score 3):

How frequently are people running `SELECT *`?? Typically, people list out each column in the select statement. Just add the column to the end, and adjust like `SELECT last_col, first_col, second_col ...`

---

Alternatively, create a VIEW that runs a select statement with the column ordering you want.

Rename the table to something else, and name the view to the table, and no one would know any different

Comment: Yes, and according to Codd's relational theory, the order of columns or rows is immaterial to the database